# QUnit exports global functions

Tags: qunit

I'm trying to get QUnit to work with my production environment, and noticed that QUnit exports a log function with this definition:

```
function ( callback ) {
    config[key].push( callback );
}
```

Why does it do this? There seem to be a hole bunch of functions that are exported globally, like `begin`, `deepEqual`, `done`, etc etc. Isn't it better if all these functions are within a namespace instead?

Shouldn't this behaviour be noted in the documentation? I had another log function defined in my codebase (shorthand for console.log), and this rendered strange bugs from QUnits side because `log("a log message")` is not correct usage of QUnit's log function.

Is there a way to contain QUnit within its namespace? Giving the code an object instead of `window` does not work.